How to Exclude AWS auto config classes in spring boot 3.3.0?
I got this exception while running a spring boot application locally, I started getting this exception when I upgraded spring boot version to 3.3.0:
Error:
The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
- org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration

sample pom.xml:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository. -->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Code:
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Profile("local")
class MyClass{

}

I need this config class to make the app not connect to AWS and run locally without any issue. Any idea how to fix this issue?
If I don't have the config class above, I get this exception:
 com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials 
from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and 
AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), 
SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials 
from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey)


Any org.springframework.cloud.aws.* classes are not compatible with spring boot 3.x. See https://awspring.io/ for the latest

@spencergibb How can I exclude aws auto config classes? because if I don't, I get this exception com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey) 

remove spring-cloud-starter-aws-*. It's not compatible woth boot 3.x

@spencergibb the correct statement is that the 2.x version of spring-cloud-starter-aws is not compatible with spring boot 3.x.  MA1 - use spring-cloud-starter-aws 3.x instead.

See my first comment

Spring Cloud AWS 3.2.0 was released few weeks ago which is compatible with Spring Boot 3.3.x
Also, I see you are using old project in dependencies. We have moved to repositories since Spring Cloud AWS is not part of Spring Cloud release train anymore.
You want to upgrade you dependencies to:
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>



 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
 </dependency>

